# Understanding time in location for each user: using the shift function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking at the below to work out the amount of time each user spends in each location.

It's working great, but the problem is the line that shows `-4.0`. This is a new user & it's the first country they've been identified in - until I see them move countries, I can't calculate the length of time that they've been in that location.

For the first location of each user, I need the result to be set to NaN as it is for user 1.

Is this possible?

```
df2['time_in_loc'] = df2['hour'] - df2['hour'].shift(1)
In [36]: df2
Out[36]:
                      hour  hop  time_in_loc
userid      country
82718927392 UK           0    1          NaN
            Spain        2    2          2.0
            Portugal     4    3          2.0
47294872934 India        0    1         -4.0
            UK          15    2         15.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check `groupby` with `diff`

```
df.groupby(level=0).diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use your `.shift` method, you'd need to first create a mask that checks if the `userid` is the same. Since `.shift` is not implemented for a non-DatetimeIndex, you can fall back to `numpy`. `np.roll` will wrap around, so we define our own `.shift` function that does not wrap.

```
import numpy as np

def shift(x, n):
        return np.concatenate((np.full(n, np.nan), x[:-n]))

m = shift(df2.index.get_level_values(0), 1) == df2.index.get_level_values(0)
df2.loc[m, 'time_in_loc'] = (df2.hour - df2.hour.shift(1))[m]
```

Output:

```
                      hour  hop  time_in_loc
userid      country                         
82718927392 UK           0    1          NaN
            Spain        2    2          2.0
            Portugal     4    3          2.0
47294872934 India        0    1          NaN
            UK          15    2         15.0
```